# Is every variable and register name just a pointer in NASM Assembly?

Tags: pointers, assembly, nasm, conceptual, language-concepts

There are [] operations which are similar to dereferencing in high-level languages. So does that mean that every variable and register name is just a pointer or are pointers a high-level languages idea and have no use in Assembly?

Comment: If we're talking about 32bit registers, then what registers hold is a 32 bit value.  Whether that is a number (say: the amount of karma points you have), a letter (like: 'A') or a pointer to memory depends on what the register is being used for.

Comment: ...what the register is being use for for the one or few clocks of a particular operation.   then they go back to being some bits...with no meaning...

Comment: assembly language is specific to the tool (assembler) not the target (x86)(there are many incompatible x86 assembly languages).   some use [] or () to indicate a level of indirection a register by itself would often indicate the contents of that register are the operand or the register is the destination.  and the brackets or parenthesis would indicate a register indirect type addressing mode where the register contents are an address of an operand or destination for the operation.  Which is like a pointer in C, yes.

Comment: same goes for labels which are basically addresses to something (pointers in themselves) and if an assembly language supports them at all as operands and then if allows indirection of them it would likewise indicate the bits at that address are the operand or the bits at that address are the address to the operand.

Comment: pointers are afaik a C idea, but some folks learn one language before another and the concept is the same, from a programming perspective you have some bits that point at some other bits.  they are the address to a location that contains the bits of interest.  and [] is often used for that.   Just like *hello or hello[] would in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointers are a useful concept in asm, but I wouldn't say that symbol names are truly *pointers*.  They're addresses, but they aren't pointers because there's no storage holding them (except metadata, and embedded into the machine code), and thus you can't modify them.  A pointer can be incremented.

---

*Variables* are a high-level concept that doesn't truly exist in assembly.  Asm has labels which you can put at any byte position in any section, including `.data`, `.text`, or whatever.  Along with directives like `dd`, you can reserve space for a global variable and attach a symbol to it.  (But a variable's value can temporarily be in a register, or for its whole lifetime if it's a local variable.  The high-level concept of a variable doesn't have to map to static storage with a label.)

Types like integer vs. pointer also don't really exist in assembly; everything is just bytes that you can load into an integer, XMM, or even x87 FP register.  (And you don't really have to think of that as type-punning to integer and back if you use `eax` to copy the bytes of a `float` from one memory location to another, you're just loading and storing to copy bytes around.)

---

But on the other hand, a pointer is a low-enough level concept still be highly relevant in assembly.  We have the stack pointer (RSP) which usually holds a valid address, pointing to some memory we're using as stack space.  (You *can* use the RSP register to hold values that aren't valid addresses, though.  In that case you're not using it as a pointer.  But at any time you could execute a `push` instruction, or `mov eax, [rsp]`, and cause an exception from the invalid address.)

**A pointer is an object that holds the address of another object.**  (I'm using "object" in C terms here: any byte[s] of storage that you can access, including something like an `int`.  Not objected as in object-oriented programming.)  So a pointer is basically a type of integer data, especially in assembly for a flat memory model where there aren't multiple components to it.  For a segmented memory model, a seg:off far pointer is a pair of integers.

So any valid address stored anywhere in register or memory can usefully be thought of as a pointer.

**But no, a symbol defined by a label is not a pointer.  Conceptually, I think it's important to think of it as just a label.**  A pointer is itself an object (some bytes of storage), and thus can be modified.  e.g. increment a pointer.  But a symbol is just a way to reference some fixed position.

---

**In C terms, a symbol is like a `char symbol[]`**, not a `char *symbol = NULL;`  If you use bare `symbol`, you get the address.  Like `mov edi, symbol` in NASM syntax.  (Or `mov edi, OFFSET symbol` in GNU .intel_syntax or MASM.  See also [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register) for practical considerations like using RIP-relative LEA if 32-bit absolute addresses don't work.)

You can deref any symbol in asm to access the bytes there, whether that's `mov eax, [main]` to load the first 4 bytes of machine code of that function, or `mov eax, [global_arr + rdi*8]` to index into an array, or [any other x86 addressing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes).  (Caveat: [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) for that last example).

But you *can't* do `arr++`; that makes no sense.  There is no storage anywhere holding that address.  It's embedded into the machine code of your program at each site that uses it.  It's **not a pointer**. (Note that C `arr[4] = 1` compiles to different asm depending on `char *arr;` vs. `char arr[]`, but in asm you have to manually load the pointer value from wherever *it's* stored, and then deref it with some offset.)

**If you have a label in asm whose address you want to use in C, but that *isn't* attached to some bytes of storage**, you usually want to declare it as `extern const char end_of_data_section[];` or whatever.

So for example you can do `size_t data_size = data_end - data_start;` and get the size in bytes as a link-time constant, if you arranged for those symbols to be at the end/start of your `.data` section.  With a linker script or with `global data_end` / `data_end:` in your NASM source.  Probably at the same address as some other symbol, for the start.

Answer (score 3):

Assembly language doesn't have variables, pointers or type checking. It has addresses and registers (and no type checking).

A variable (e.g. in C) is a higher level thing - a way to abstract the location of a piece of data so that you don't have to care if the compiler felt like putting it in a register or in memory. A variable also has a type; which is used to detect some kinds of bugs, and used to allow the compiler to automatically convert data to a different type for you.

A pointer (e.g. in C) is a variable (see above). The main difference between a pointer and a "not pointer" is the type of data it contains - for a pointer the variable typically contains an address, but a pointer is not just an address, it's the address of something with a type. This is important - if it was just an address then the compiler wouldn't know how big it is, couldn't detect some kinds of bugs, and couldn't automatically convert data (e.g. consider what would happen for `int foo = *pointer_to_char;` if the compiler didn't know what type of data the pointer points to).