# mov instruction's different behavior with variables and registers in assembly x86 NASM on Linux

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers

The purpose of this program is to divide 36 by 10 and print the remainder (6) to the screen. The code I specified below doesn't work. I figured out that it was because on my marked line I was putting the value itself into `ecx` and not the address of that value in memory.

I later changed the code so that it first puts the value into a variable, and then did `mov ecx, variable` (which actually puts the address of the variable, not the value onto the register `ecx`). And it worked.

1. Why doing `mov ecx, variable` puts `variables`'s **address** into `ecx`'s value, but doing `mov ecx, edx` puts `edx`'s **value** into `ecx` value?
2. How can I specify the address of a register and put it in another register's value?

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    
    ; division
    mov eax,36
    mov ebx,10
    mov edx,0   ; cleaning edx before division
    div ebx
    add edx,0x30 ; converting the remainder (integer) into ascii digit
    
    ; display result
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,edx        ; pay attention to this line
    mov edx,1
    int 80h
    
    ; exit
    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
```

Comment: Registers are not addressible in any way.

Comment: 1. Because that's the syntax the NASM designers chose. Other assemblers may do it differently. For example, with gas, `mov ecx, variable` does load the **value** of `variable`; it requires $ before the variable name to load its address. 2. You cannot.

Comment: @prl: in GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix`, you need `mov ecx, OFFSET variable`.  A `$` only applies to AT&T syntax, like `mov $variable, %ecx`.  (GAS assembles `.intel_syntax noprefix; mov ecx, $variable` as a load from a symbol whose name includes a dollar sign, with the relocation entry being `R_X86_64_32S $variable`)

Comment: Re: NASM symbols and why it makes sense that a non-register symbol uses the address instead of loading from it: [Is every variable and register name just a pointer in NASM Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71543020) makes the analogy to labels being like C `char variable[];`.  You could think of other things (registers and `equ` constants) as being actual values, though.